# CAShapeLayer redraws itself when any other animation occurs?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation, core-graphics

I have a graphic that is comprised of `CGMutablePaths`. I'm taking these `CGMutablePaths`, and separating them into `CAShapeLayers` based on the different area of the graphic they represent. Below is a snippet of the code using to accomplish this:

```
_initialSize = _size = CGSizeMake(168.784,127.842);
CGRect shapeLayerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _initialSize.width, _initialSize.height);

CAShapeLayer *eyeBallShapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
eyeBallShapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1].CGColor;
eyeBallShapeLayer.bounds = shapeLayerFrame;
CGMutablePathRef eyeBallMutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable();

CAShapeLayer *eyeWhiteShapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
eyeWhiteShapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1].CGColor;
eyeWhiteShapeLayer.bounds = shapeLayerFrame;
CGMutablePathRef eyeWhiteMutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGMutablePathRef mutablePath;

mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(mutablePath, NULL, 168.78,127.79);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(mutablePath, NULL, 155.56,127.13);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(mutablePath, NULL, 156.23,126.83,156.73,125.92,157.06,125.31);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(mutablePath, NULL, 157.60,122.36,157.84,119.11,159.77,116.67);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(mutablePath, NULL, 160.75,115.23,160.44,113.42,160.52,111.78);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(mutablePath, NULL, 160.58,111.83,160.64,111.88,160.70,111.94);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(mutablePath, NULL, 161.05,112.27,161.27,112.68,161.47,113.10);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(mutablePath, NULL, 161.63,113.46,161.78,113.82,161.96,114.16);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(mutablePath, NULL, 161.97,114.18,161.98,114.20,161.99,114.21);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(mutablePath, NULL, 162.13,114.47,162.29,114.71,162.51,114.92);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(mutablePath, NULL, 162.52,114.92);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(mutablePath, NULL, 162.96,115.28,163.36,115.65,163.74,116.05);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(mutablePath, NULL, 165.44,117.86,166.53,120.17,167.18,122.59);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(mutablePath, NULL, 167.25,122.86,167.32,123.13,167.38,123.40);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(mutablePath, NULL, 167.63,124.48,167.79,125.58,167.89,126.67);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(mutablePath, NULL, 167.90,126.94,168.05,127.13,168.23,127.30);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(mutablePath, NULL, 168.41,127.47,168.63,127.62,168.78,127.79);
CGPathCloseSubpath(mutablePath);
CGPathAddPath(eyeBallMutablePath, NULL, mutablePath);
CGPathRelease(mutablePath);


//a whole lot of paths being loaded in much the same way as above

_shapeLayers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

eyeBallShapeLayer.path = eyeBallMutablePath;
[_shapeLayers addObject:eyeBallShapeLayer];
CGPathRelease(eyeBallMutablePath);
[eyeBallShapeLayer release];

eyeWhiteShapeLayer.path = eyeWhiteMutablePath;
[_shapeLayers addObject:eyeWhiteShapeLayer];
CGPathRelease(eyeWhiteMutablePath);
[eyeWhiteShapeLayer release];
```

I attach these shapeLayers to a views `layer` property, and the graphic draws fine. The problem that I'm getting is the `CAShapeLayers` are redrawing themselves when any animation occurs. IE if a modal view is pulled up or there a navigational transition, it redraws itself. I have functionality where the bars disappear when the user taps the screen (like the photos app) and it redraws itself during this. It also redraws itself when I'm dragging the shape. For some of my graphics that have a decent amount of paths, it is causing the animations to stutter when it's redrawing itself.

So my question is, does anyone know why this is happening? What am I doing wrong that's causing this to happen? This wasn't happening when I was simply drawing the graphic in drawRect, so I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

By default a `CALayer` will be redrawn for every frame in an animation. What you'll need to do is tell your layers that they should be [rasterized](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/shouldRasterize). By doing this, your layers will only be redrawn when the contents of the layer change, not when it is involved in an animation.

If you add the following code for each of your shape layers, the animations should run a lot smoother.

```
[shapeLayer setRasterizationScale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]];
[shapeLayer setShouldRaseterize:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it supposed to be redrawn in every frame of an animation it's not involved in? I did try what you mentioned above and it helps performance, but it's still redrawing itself and stuttering.

Comment: Technically it is involved in the animation. For showing/hiding a modal view, it needs to draw more or less of the layer to the screen. For a navigational transition, it needs to shift where it is drawn on the screen. One thing you could try doing is adding the above code for the layer that that shapeLayers are put into and removing it for the shapeLayers. That way only one layer needs to be rasterized instead of multiple.